# Heroku Buildpack Multi rejected push due to no Cedar-supported app detected (browserify-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, npm, browserify

I have got an rails app in which I use browserify-rails gem.
I followed [instructions](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails#deploying-to-heroku) from their readme:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
$ cat .buildpacks
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

`package.json` and `.buildpacks` are checked in repo.

Unfortunately push fails:

```
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to
```

That was a first deploy try to fresh heroku app.